# Airflow DAG - Start kubernetes Job

Tags: python, airflow

using airflow 2.0

Is it possible to lunch Kubernetes Job?
job is defined in yaml file. e.g.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
```

There is a `KubernetesPodOperator` that can be used in DAG file but seems it can't be used to lunch a`Job`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone did write a KubernetesJobOperator.  You can see that [here](https://github.com/LamaAni/KubernetesJobOperator) and [here](https://pypi.org/project/airflow-kubernetes-job-operator/).

I'm not sure why you would do that but this is the author's reasoning:
[image]

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow_kubernetes_job_operator'. How to import it in Airflow K8s (DAG comes from GitSync)?